# ng-zorro-antd Modal not inheriting Providers from parent

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

Should the ng-zorro-antd Modal inherit providers from the parent?

I'm using the NzModalService to create the modal.

- declare the provider in the parent component.
- declare the service in the child modal component constructor.

The service in the child modal component is a new instance of the service. Should it not have been inherited from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Now the child component's NzModalService gets the parent component's NzModalService instance by `@SkipSelf()`, thus some properties are inherited from the parent.